# Entity framework - invalid column name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF6 and I'm getting an error Invalid column name 'ContentArticleHOAsubdivisionId'.  Here's are the relevant models, that I'm trying to link together:

```
public partial class ContentArticleHOAsubdivision
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public long ContentArticleId { get; set; }
    public short SubdivisionHOAId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ContentArticleId")]
    public virtual ContentArticleHOA ContentArticleHOA { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubdivisionHOA> SubdivisionsHOA { get; set; }
}

public partial class SubdivisionHOA
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("TopTierDivisionHOA")]
    public short Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ContentArticleHOAsubdivisionId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ContentArticleHOAsubdivisionId")]
    public virtual ContentArticleHOAsubdivision ContentArticleHOAsubdivision { get; set; }
    public virtual TopTierDivisionHOA TopTierDivisionHOA { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using code-first and the error occurs when I try to query the data.  Here's the full query:

```
            query = context.ContentArticleHOA.Where(
                    c => c.ContentArticleHOAsubdivisions.Any(cs => cs.SubdivisionsHOA.Any(s => s.Name == subdivision)) &&
                    c.ContentArticleHOAsubdivisions.Any(cs => cs.SubdivisionsHOA.Any(s => s.TopTierDivisionHOA.Name == topTierDivision)) &&
                    c.Content.ContentType == ContentType.Article &&
                    c.Content.StreamHOA == true &&
                    c.Content.OnHold == false &&
                    DateTimeOffset.UtcNow >= c.Content.StartDate &&
                    DateTimeOffset.UtcNow <= c.Content.EndDate
                    );
```

What's the correct code to link the tables, or how can I fix this?

Comment: _when_ do you get that error - when you try to query the data?  Is this code-first or database-first?

Comment: This is code-first, and the error occurs when querying the data.

Comment: Do the columns get created in the database?

Comment: I've already manually added the tables and columns using SQL.

Comment: The SubdivisionHOA table shouldn't have a ContentArticleHOAsubdivisionId column, as the ContentArticleHOAsubdivision table should be able to link to the 'Id' column on SubdivisionHOA by using it's foreign key column 'SubdivisionHOAId'